# How would I use sed and/or awk/grep to edit the line following a matched string?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a large text file that needs some changes. I need to do this by first locating lines that have a particular common string, and then editing the line directly after that. So for example, if I ran this `grep` command:

```
# grep -A1 important_string gianttextfile.txt
important_string
change_this
```

I would want to first locate `important_string`, and then modify `change_this` to be something else, several times throughout a document. I cannot just modify all `change_this` entries because many of them need to stay as they are, it's just the ones following this particular string that I need to change.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Should a line just after `important_string` be tested for `important_string`: before substitution? after substitution? only if there was no substitution? or never?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm maybe not understanding what you're asking. There's two possible values that can follow `important_string`. `change_this` is one, `new_value` is the other (there's some other junk on that line too but that can stay as it is). What I need is effectively `# sed -i 's/change_this/new_value/' file.txt` but applied only to the line immediately following each occurrence of `important_string`.

Comment: These are example strings, not your actual strings, right? If the actual strings were `foo`, `ofa` and `f` respectively, and the input was `foo`, `ofafoo`, `foofa`, `ofaoo`, `ofa` (5 lines), then `ofafoo` should be changed to `ffoo`. But there's also `foo` there, before and after the replacement. So should the third line be changed? If yes, then `foo` in the third line will disappear. Should the fourth line be changed because of the disappearing `foo` in the third? If yes, then `foo` will appear in the fourth. Should the fifth line be changed because of the appearing `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/important_string/ {n;s/change_this/new_value/}'
```

Notes:

- Remember `important_string` and `change_this` are parsed as regular expressions.
- Any line where `s` is performed is *not* tested for `important_string`, so it cannot trigger `s` for the next line. This means a snippet like this:

  ```
  …
  foo                #  this line does not trigger s for the next line
  important_string   #  this line triggers s for the next line
  important_string   #  s is performed here
  change_this        #  s in not performed here
  …
  ```

  will not change. A variant that always tests for `important_string` is

  ```
  sed ':start; /important_string/ {n;s/change_this/new_value/;b start}'
  ```
- If `s` could make `important_string` appear or disappear then you may want to test for `important_string` before substitution and/or after substitution; or not to test if `s` made a successful substitution. This answer does not cover all these cases.
- Use `s/…/…/g` if needed.
- Use `sed -i … file` if needed.